# Update Eventbrite Google Analytics tracking code via API

Tags: php, eventbrite

Is it possible to update the [Google Analytics tracking ID](http://help.eventbrite.com/customer/portal/articles/428835-google-analytics-integration) for an Eventbrite event via the Eventbrite API?

I don't see any documentation for this in the [Eventbrite API](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/), perhaps there's something undocumented available with the [event_update](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_update/) method?

Answer (score 0):

Updating an event's Google Analytics ID is currently not possible via the api.